# Television episode about scientists discovering the Grand Unification Theory, as each one discovers it they begin to vanish

Tags: story-identification, tv, science, physics

I'm still trying to find another sci-fi show/series/episode - it has similarities to the one *Twilight Zone* with the experimental aircraft ([And When the Sky was Opened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_When_the_Sky_Was_Opened)). But in this one, a bunch of scientists stumble onto ideas that put them on the track of what amounts to a Grand Unification Theory that explains the fundamental physics of the universe.
As each of them begins to understand it and see what it means, they end up vanishing and no one [outside the remaining team members] remembers them until eventually, the story ends with a janitor sweeping the floor of a now-empty laboratory. I recall there was at least one woman on the team and I seem to remember it in black-and-white.
(In the Twilight Zone episode, it ends with a different headline about the crash in the desert - so the crew is all remembered again, but with a different end-result. In this one, the people were entirely erased from existence for figuring out the secret of the universe)

I recall one of the premises is that when the first scientist realized the implications of the new theory he is amazed that no one had put the pieces together before (which kind of sets you up for the result).

I can't remember what series/show it was from and can't seem to find it anywhere! I'm starting to think maybe the episode itself was wiped out of existence and I'm next because I still remember it!

Comment: The writings of Sam Hughes at qntm.org play with those themes on occasion. But I don't think any are TV episodes.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RetGone is the TV Tropes page for this kind of thing. But I don't see any live action TV or movie entries matching this description. Are you sure it was something you watched? Not read?

Comment: Was it a series that you watched regularly?  Do you recall any other episodes that might trigger our collective or individual memories?

Comment: I vaguely remember viewing something very similar if not this very story 50s/60s.

Comment: @StephenCollings Yeah pretty sure, because I can recall the campy style of the woman/actress pretending to be a scientist and acting all shocked when no one remembered her missing colleague. ;)

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt that's the thing. I originally thought it was one of the typicals when I first recalled it (e.g. twilight zone or outer limits) but I went through literally all of them and didn't find it.

Comment: I also vaguely recall that it was one of those types of series where a narrator 'sums up' over the scene at the end as the janitor was sweeping up in the empty laboratory and some other scientist was showing someone into the "this lab is empty in here..." type finish.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_series?wprov=sfla1

Comment: still no luck finding this show/episode *sigh*